# Why training not using the full training data set in TensorFlow text tutorial

Tags: tensorflow

I have a question after reading the text classification tutorial of TensorFlow: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification_with_hub

In the data preparation phase (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification_with_hub#download_the_imdb_dataset), it says the training data contains `15,000 examples for training`.

However, in the model training phase (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification_with_hub#train_the_model), the code uses 10000 samples.

```
history = model.fit(train_data.shuffle(10000).batch(512),
                    epochs=20,
                    validation_data=validation_data.batch(512),
                    verbose=1)
```

Could anyone explain why the training dose not uses the whole training dataset (i.e., 15000 samples)? Thanks.

Comment: Don't think it needs a full answer. Basically they/you are saving a section of the data to test against. If you trained on that data, then you wouldnt be able to see how accurate the training was.

Comment: The training dataset has already been split into training and validation. My question is given there are 15000 samples in the training set, why the model uses only 10000 of them, instead of all 15000. I am new to machine learning; so I may miss some basic concept here.